# ajax call passing incorrect value to java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML Document with a number of divs. Each div has a unique Id.
I've created a script so when I drag and drop another element onto one of my divs it should recognise which div it has been dropped on.

- As an example if the id of the div is '5':
- In the alert in the code I see '5'.
- In the second alert in my doAjaxPost method I see '5'
- but when i call ajax and pass in the categoryId to a spring mvc method
  when the code hits the setter it changes to include something like
  '234674,5'.

Any ideas what is happening and how to resolve it?

```
My code:
$(".category").bind("drop", function (event) {
      if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
      doAjaxPost($(this).attr("id"));
      return false;
});

function doAjaxPost(categoryId) {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/aMethod.html",
        data: "categoryId=" + categoryId,
        success: function(response){
            // we have the response
            },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
});
}
```

This is the spring mvc method that is called:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createEvent(@ModelAttribute(value="Item")
Item item, BindingResult result) {
    itemService.saveItem(item);
    return "A Response";
}
```

Item Object:

```
package com.pk.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "bi_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "bi_category_id")
private String categoryId;

@Column(name = "bi_item_name")
private String itemName;

public String getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}
public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}
public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}


}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the categoryId parameter have correct value? Maybe debug the javascript in browser, to verify this.

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I have the alerts for. All the way through the javascript it is '5' but as soon as it sets the categoryId on the java object it has changed.

Comment: You should be able to see what is being sent to the server by using Firebug's console and looking at the params of the post request. If that is as expected, then the problem lies in the Java code.

Comment: would you provide your back-end bean too?

Comment: I used firebug and the value is correct through the javascript. I put a breakpoint just before the setCategoryId and the value here is wrong. Could it be anything to do with how spring binds the object and values together maybe?

Comment: Issue resolved below, cheers for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value received is likely to be due a duplicated parameter (two parameters with the same name).

If you are calling `http://foo.com?idDiv=5` server will receive 5.
If you are calling `http://foo.com?idDiv=5&idDiv=234674` server will receive 5,234674.

As @MarkChorley suggested I would double-check what is actually being sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. That is correct, just found the issue now, had a duplicate categoryId from the shortcut i was dropping on to the div. Makes sense now.